# when will a branching process be recurrent or transient

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Consider a branching process with offspring distribution given by
>   $\{p_n\}$. We will make the process into an irreducible Markov chain
>   by asserting that if the population ever dies out, then the next
>   generation will have one new individual [in other words, $p(0,1) =
>  1$]. For which $\{p_n\}$ will this chain be positive recurrent, null
>   recurrent, transient?

This is an exercise from Lawler's Introduction to Stochastic Processes.

---

I believe the result should be (let $\mu=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ip_i$): If $\mu < 1$, it is positive recurrent; if $\mu = 1$, it is null recurrent; if $\mu > 1$, it is transient. But I don't know how to prove it. Thanks for help!

Comment: Presumably, the other transition probabilities are given by the offspring distribution (and transitions to zero correspond to when the population dies out)?

Comment: Recall that the probability of eventual extinction is $1$ when $mu\leqslant 1$ and is strictly less than $1$ when $\mu>1$